# How can I use a while loop to display this output?

Tags: python

I have this code right here

```
value = 0
while value < 5:
   print("@")
   value += 1
enter code here
```

When I run this code this is what is displayed.

```
@
@
@
@
@
```

I want this to be displayed.

```
@
 @
  @
   @
    @
```

I've looked up how to add spaced between outputs of code but to no success.  If anyone could help me with this that would be awesome!

Comment: Let's walk through what you know. Do you know how to print `n` spaces for some arbitrary `n`?

Comment: `print(" " * value + "@")` and `print("@".rjust(value + 1, " "))`

Answer (score 6):

You can multiply strings with ints to repeat the string. So just multiply some spaces:

```
value = 0
while value < 5:
    print(" "*value + "@")
    value += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you you're asking to print `value` number of spaces before the `@`.

Change your print statement to this:

```
print(" " * value + "@")
```

On the first loop iteration, `value` is zero and so it prints zero extra spaces before the `@`, on the second iteration it prints one extra space, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

We can do something like this:

```
value = 0
while value < 5:
   print(" " * value + "@")
   value += 1
```

Output:

```
@
 @
  @
   @
    @
```

Answer (score 0):

```
value = 1
stringy = " "
while value < 5:
    print('{}@'.format(stringy * value))
    value +=1
```

this will do it with a len of your string